# Difference in Graphics output between Mac and Windows

Tags: graphics3d, windows, mac-os-x, rendering

This code:

```
openCone[{{x1_, y1_, z1_}, {x2_, y2_, z2_}}, r_] := {CapForm[None], 
  Tube[{{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}}, {r, 0}]}

arrowHead[size_] := Arrowheads[{{size, 0.93, 
  {Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, .25]}], 0}}}]

Manipulate[
 Lcone = Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Dashed, Black]], 
    LightGray, openCone[{{0, 0, 5}, {0, 0, 0}}, 4]}, Boxed -> False, 
   ViewPoint -> {5, 5, 2}];
 Lvec = Graphics3D[{Black, Arrowheads[0.05], 
    Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {Sqrt[4^2 - \[Rho]L^2], \[Rho]L, 5}}, 
      0.05]]}];
 Scone = Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Dashed, Black]], Gray, 
    openCone[{{0, 0, 7}, {0, 0, 0}}, 3]}, Boxed -> False];
 Svec = Graphics3D[{Black, Arrowheads[0.05], 
    Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {Sqrt[3^2 - \[Rho]S^2], \[Rho]S, 7}}, 
      0.05]]}];
 Jvec = Graphics3D[{Black, Arrowheads[0.1], 
    Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, Sqrt[5^2 + 7^2]}}, 0.05]]}];
 Show[Lcone, Lvec, Scone, Svec, Jvec, Method -> {"TubePoints" -> 400}], {\[Rho]L, 1.12}, {\[Rho]S, 
  2.96}]
```

produces this result when run on a Windows (10, 64 bit) machine:

[image]

and this when run on a Mac:

[image]

Version: Mathematica 11.3

--

I have a Windows machine but I like how the arrows come out on the Mac version... how can I fix this?

Comment: I don’t have a windows machine to test on, but take a look at [`RenderingOptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RenderingOptions.html). For example I see the setting for Direct3D is only available for windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is a known issue of 11.3 Mathematica on Windows 10...

https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1302365